# How to update an SQL database using visual studio?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I've created a basic HTML form on visual studio, I've managed to connect an sql database to visual studio, I'm just looking for a way to update the fields in the database with what is typed into the form, when the user clicks submit. Hope this makes sense.

Also, would there be any language in particular I could use to hard code this in myself?

Thanks

Comment: Hi matthewshaw2, thanks for your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask; your post is broad and needs more focus. Posts should ask one thing and one thing only (and you are welcome to ask multiple questions!).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a very vast answer here. Basically a whole tutorial to begin with. There are a lot of ways to implement crud operations from Visual Studio.

I suggest you go through this tutorial to understand crud operations clearly. this is the easiest way to implement database operations from VS

[CRUD Operation in C# App](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/crud-operation-in-c-sharp-application#:%7E:text=CRUD%20operation%2C%20using%20C%23%20is%20the%20common%20program,from%20the%20database%2C%20using%20C%23%20Server%20side%20code.)